# Python import error, cannot find module

Tags: python, import

My project structure is like this:

```
dir A/
    main.py
    __init__.py
    modules/
        a.py
        __init__.py
        components/
            b.py
            c.py
            __init__.py
```

In `main.py`, I've written `from modules.a import xxx`. In `a.py`, I want to import module `b.py` and in `b.py`, I want to import `c.py`.

Here's the problem, I wrote `from components.b import xxx` in `a.py`, I got import error when I ran `main.py`. I got the same error if I write `from c import xxx` in `b.py`. But if I ran `b.py` directly, it went well. I've tried many times and found that I have to write all import sentences considering `dir A` as the root directory. For example, if I write `from modules.components.b import xxx` in `a.py` and `from modules.components.c import xxx` in `b.py`, the program goes well.

Someone says that change environment path can solve this problem. But don't I have to set the path again and again once I change the position of the whole project?

Is there any decent solution? I'm very glad to hear someone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Relative imports.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

```
from .components.b import xxx
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I'm so foolish.